# laravel insert a multiple inputs

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

i have issue in laravel 5.1 with insert a multiple inputs intro DB.

i build a  query code for multiple inputs and after that i send them to controller but i have there a issues to insert it to DB

how i can insert the inputs to db if the results its like this:

```
{"_token":"C6m83bcZKaQsOtRiYEKxJAzzZjvdLerl9QpsvSSs","client_id":["aJQsijwqFVG9r0","aJQsijwqFVG9r0"],"short":["4","11"],"url":["567567567567","3453434534"]}
```

the code:

HTML:

```
                 <form class="js-validation-material form-horizontal push-10-t" action="{!! url() !!}/addreg" method="post">
                                {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div id="buildyourform"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                </form>
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#add").click(function() {
                    var intId = $("#buildyourform div.form").length + 1;
                    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"form col-sm-6 col-lg-6\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"><div class=\"form-material\">");
                    var client_id = $("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"client_id[]\" value=\"{!! $task->client_id !!}\" class=\"form-control\" />");
                    var langname = $("<select type=\"text\" name=\"short[]\" class=\"form-control\">{!! $data['langs'] !!}</select>");
                    var url = $("<input type=\"text\" name=\"url[]\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Insert a url..\" />");
                    var label = ("<label for=\"date\"><h3 class=\"block-title\">Lang" + intId + "</h3></label>");
                    var removeButton = $("<button class=\"btn btn-danger  btn-xs push-5-r push-10\" type=\"button\"><i class=\"fa fa-times\"></i></button>");
                    removeButton.click(function() {
                        $(this).parent().remove();
                    });

                    $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
                    $("#field" + intId + " .form-material").append(client_id,langname,url,removeButton,label);

                });
            });
           </script>
```

the results need to be in the DB like:

```
    DB::table('table')->insert([
        ['client_id' => $request->client_id],
        ['short' => $request->short],
        ['url' => $request->url],
    ]);
```

for each input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are sending multiples inputs with the same name, so it only get the last one.

Everytime you do and "add" try to wrap them in a div with a class *(example: "foo")*. So you will get some "foo" divs.

Create a hidden input called for example "items"

```
{{ Form::hidden('items') }}
```

Next you have to overwrite the click function of the submit button:

```
$('#submit-form').click(function(e){
    a = {};
    $.each($('.foo'), function(k,v){
        a[k] = $(v).find(':input').serializeArray()
    });
    $('input[name="items"]').val(JSON.stringify(a));
    $('#form').submit()
}
```

And in the controller:

```
$items = json_decode(Input::get('items'), true);
```

Then you have an array with all of your inputs.